# Can not change UIWebView background color to clearcolor from Attribute inspector in XIB

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview

I've come across a strange issue. In my application I have one UIWebView which displays some description. As I want same background color on the whole page I set the Background color property to **clearcolor** via **Attribute inspector** in XIB displayed in screen below. But setting property from **Attribute inspector** does not work for me.

So I wrote a code in `ViewDidLoad` and worked perfectly:

```
webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
```

[image]

My question is why did not background color property work from **Attribute inspector** in Xib and worked when I manually coded it?? Do I consider it a bug?

Thanks.

**P.S. : I use Xcode 4.0.2**

Answer (score 8):

You can change `UIWebView` Like  this: set `Opaque` property to `NO` and then set the background color, e.g.:

```
[webView setOpaque:NO]; 
webview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]; // any color you'd like
```

Comment: Work for me that uiwebview in storyboard